# How to show Gradle module dependency tree

Tags: android, gradle

I tried using

```
./gradlew androidDependencies
```

but that shows all dependencies. I just want to see **only** module dependencies, e.g. as defined in all `build.gradle`s

```
dependencies {
  
    implementation project(':moduleA')
    implementation project(':moduleB')
    implementation project(':moduleC')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-dependency-graph-generator-plugin

You can use this plugin to create "your project module dependency graph"

> ./gradlew generateProjectDependencyGraph

[image: app module dependency graph]

or "whole dependency graph".

> ./gradlew generateDependencyGraph

Answer (score 1):

You mean like

```
gradle moduleA:dependencies
```

This should show the dependencies related to moduleA

For the whole dependencies Tree with no module selected

```
gradle dependencies
```